# C pass reference to parameter

Tags: c

I ran into the following in some legacy C code:

```
typedef struct _somestruct_ {
 /* .... */
} SomeStruct_t

static void do_one_thing(SomeStruct_t *pInput){
   /* Do some read-only stuff with pInput */   
}


static void do_many_thing(SomeStruct_t input){
   do_one_thing(&input);
}
```

Does C actually permit this, even though the thing will likely blow up if `do_one_thing` is actually modified to write to `pInput`?

Comment: Why do you expect it to blow up if `*pInput` is written to?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely legal C code.  The code `do_one_thing(&input)` is simply passing the address of a parameter to the function `do_one_thing`.  There is nothing wrong with this.

It's not even an issue if `do_one_thing` writes to `pInput`.  The address is valid and points to a mutable value.  There is nothing wrong with doing an update.  Consider

```
typedef struct _somestruct_ {
 int field;
} SomeStruct_t

static void do_one_thing(SomeStruct_t *pInput){
  // Completely legal  
  pInput->field = 42;
}

static void do_many_thing(SomeStruct_t input){
  do_one_thing(&input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess ill have to keep looking for where that stack snafu comes from then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes C will permit this, `do_many_thing` will have a copy of `SomeStruct_t` passed as `input`, then you pass the address to `do_one_thing` which is free to read or write to the struct. The caller to `do_many_thing` will not see any changes performed on the struct passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly legal code. And it also won't blow up if do_one_thing writes to the data of pInput. This can also be perfectly valid if the programmer is aware that the changes do_one_thing did are gone at the end of do_many_thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically passing a pointer to the **value** of `SomeStruct_t input`. `SomeStruct_t input` is a value on the stack, `do_one_thing` will then modify the stack value pointer, but no changes will be seen by the caller of `do_many_thing`.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have pass by reference as such so this method of passing a pointer to a variable is the only way to achieve the same semantics.

Many other languages allow you to pass by reference directly.  For example in C++ you could do it like this:

```
static void do_one_thing(SomeStruct_t& Input){
   Input.foo++;   
}
```

Then when you call the function you do it like so:

```
do_one_thing(input);
```

But without this sort of help from the language your only option is pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code listing may not be complete, so it's impossible to know for sure, but as it stands it doesn't look like it will "blow up" at all.

`do_many_thing` receives a copy of some struct as `input`.  You then modify this copy by passing it into `do_one_thing`.  Unless you are *relying* on that copy not having changed, nothing bad will happen at all.  Moreover, the caller of `do_many_thing` will not see a change to the `SomeStruct_t` passed in, so even at a higher level there would be no side effects.